# Error running shiny-server

Tags: ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server

I try to run shiny server from terminal in Ubuntu but I receive this error:

```
nik@nik-VirtualBox:~$ shiny-server
[2017-02-13 10:42:28.353] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.1.834 (Node.js v6.9.1)
[2017-02-13 10:42:28.362] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2017-02-13 10:42:28.508] [ERROR] shiny-server - Error loading config: The user 'nik' does not have permissions to run applications as one of the users in 'shiny'. Please restart shiny-server as one of the users in  'shiny'. (/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf:2:1)
[2017-02-13 10:42:28.510] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes
```

What can I do to run an app in shiny-server?

new error:

```
nik@nik-VirtualBox:~$ sudo shiny-server
[sudo] password for nik: 
[2017-02-14 01:56:52.913] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.1.834 (Node.js v6.9.1)
[2017-02-14 01:56:52.922] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2017-02-14 01:56:53.055] [WARN] shiny-server - Running as root unnecessarily is a security risk! You could be running more securely as non-root.
[2017-02-14 01:56:53.064] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
[2017-02-14 01:56:53.080] [ERROR] shiny-server - HTTP server error (0.0.0.0:3838): listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:3838
[2017-02-14 01:56:53.081] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes
```

Comment: The error message is `nik` user does not have the permission, i think you can add a `sudo` before the command.

Comment: @yundongxu thank you. It runs but it shuts down under a new error. I am not pretty sure if I have to give a file path to a shiny app in my system and this could be not from root, but I don't find how?

Comment: @yundongxu I tried to execute sudo shiny-server in the specific file path of app but again I receive the same error.

Comment: You can run the `sudo lsof -i:3838` to see if there are other process listening the 3838 port. If you see any other process, run the `sudo kill -9 PROCESSID` to kill that process.

Comment: Oh, wait. You can run the `ps aufx | grep shiny-server` to see is there any process named shiny-server, I think the shiny-server has been running automatically.

Comment: You refer to this artical https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @yundongxu thank you again for your time. I made all the steps from your last link and the `http://your_server_ip:3838/sample-apps/rmd/` but if I put another application file under sample-apps and give the name/replace the rmd is not working.

Comment: what is the permission of your new app. try using: ls -l

Answer (score 1):

Shiny server has a configuration file. By default user name is `shiny`. There is no user `shiny` in your system so server refuses to start.
I solved the problem in the following way.

```
sudo nano /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
```

There is a line:

```
run_as shiny;
```

Change `shiny` to a legit username, then restart shiny server:

```
sudo systemctl restart shiny-server
```